# Cloudcustodian - filter by tag name for on/off hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

I have the following policy:

```
policies:
  - name: stop-after-hours 
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - tag:Schedule: "OfficeHours" 
    actions:
      - stop
    mode:
      type: periodic
      schedule: "rate(10 minutes)"
      role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/LambdaRoleCloudCustodian
```

Which correctly identified my EC2 tagged with "Schedule: OfficeHours":

```
$> custodian run --dry-run -s out shutdown-out-of-office.yml
custodian.policy:INFO policy:stop-after-hours-cologne resource:ec2 region:eu-central-1 count:1 time:0.00
```

However, when I want to set the `offhour`:

```
policies:
  - name: stop-after-hours 
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - tag:Schedule: "OfficeHours" 
      - type: offhour
        offhour: 11
    actions:
      - stop
    mode:
      type: periodic
      schedule: "rate(10 minutes)"
      role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/LambdaRoleCloudCustodian
```

The instance is not identified anymore.

```
2022-07-05 12:01:04,541: custodian.policy:INFO policy:stop-after-hours-cologne resource:ec2 region:eu-central-1 count:0 time:0.78
```

I also tried

```
- type: value
  key: tag:Schedule
  value: OfficeHours
```

which doesn't work.

Any idea on how I can filter on tag name AND value here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after fiddling around quite some time, I finally found the solution.

Here's the complete policy

```
  # Stop instances tagged with "Schedule: OfficeHour" at offhour
  - name: stop-after-hours
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - tag:Schedule: OfficeHours
      - State.Name: running
      - type: offhour
        tag: Schedule
        weekends: true
        default_tz: cet
        offhour: 10
    actions:
      - stop
    mode:
      type: periodic
      schedule: "rate(10 minutes)"
      role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/LambdaRoleCloudCustodian
```

Some things to keep in mind

- Here, under `filters/type`, I have a `tag` attribute for which the value is `Schedule`. This will tell Cloudcustodian to look for any instance which has the tag `Schedule`, whatever its value. If you do not specify this, you need to tag your instance with the default `offhour` tag which is `maid_offhours`
- I also have `tag:Schedule: OfficeHours` which will filter out instances based on the tag `Schedule`'s value.
- If you want to test your policy with a dry-run, you **must** test in the current hour. So, if my `offhour` is set to `10`, then the dry-run will only be able to fetch the resource if it is run between 10:00am and 10:59am.

I hope it helps some people, I find the Cloudcustodian documentation quite difficult to understand.